# Avoiding for-loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a function as follows:

[image: Function]

My optimized matlab code is:

```
function gamma = calcGamma(H, d, delta, f)

s= size(H);
Nv = s(1);
Ne = s(2);
gamma = zeros(Ne,1);

for e =1:Ne

    hue = H(:,e);
    sdu=f./sqrt(d);

    mHUE = repmat(hue',Nv,1);
    mHVE = repmat(hue,1,Nv);
    mSDU = repmat(sdu',Nv,1);
    mSd = repmat(sdu,1,Nv);

   ss1 =  mHUE .* mHVE/delta(e) .* (mSDU-mSd).^2;
   gamma(e) = sum(ss1(:));
end
```

However, since Ne is very big, it takes quite a long time to calculate the function.

I see an similar question with a good solution, but I do not understand how it is derived.

[image]

Any solution to avoid the for-loop? Thanks

Comment: What are the typical sizes of `H`, `d`, `gamma` and `f`? And is the difference between `gamma` and `gama` intentional?

Comment: the size of H is about 10,000*2,000, d and f is about 10,000*1,gamma is 2,000. the parameter of gamma should be delta, I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will be faster, but instead of your trick with `repmat`, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). This trick is pretty similar to the [array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) that is standard in numpy and saves the creation of the large intermediate matrices like `mHUE`.

Another thing you should always do is to [move everything out of the loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion) that does not depend on `e`. It seems to me that the calculation of `sdu` is totally constant, so do that once before the loop. And I guess that `delta(e)` is a scalar, so instead of dividing the big matrices by that, do it once afterwards:

```
s= size(H);
Nv = s(1);
Ne = s(2);
gamma = zeros(Ne,1);

sdu = f./sqrt(d);
M = bsxfun(@minus, sdu', sdu).^2;

for e =1:Ne
    hue = H(:,e);
    ss1 =  bsxfun(@times, hue', hue) .* M;
    gamma(e) = sum(ss1(:));
end
gamma = gamma ./ delta;
```

It might be possible to remove the for-loop, but it is doubtful that that will increase speed, since you have just a single loop and your calculation time is anyhow dominated by the multiplication of the big matrices. Moreover, removing the for-loop will just make your function very hard to understand, so just leave it as is.

Comment: Thank you, Bas, you solution is FIVE times faster than my code.

Comment: Wow, I am glad to hear that. Make sure to test that the result is still the same. Please accept the answer if you are happy.